# New to json and javascript, help?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file which contains questions and answers like this.

```
{
    "Questions": [
        { "Q": "I enjoy playing video games" },
        { "Q": "I enjoy reading" },
        { "Q": "I enjoy watching tv" }
    ],

    "Answers": [
        {
            "a": "Strongly Agree",
            "b": "Agree",
            "c": "Neutral",
            "d": "Disagree",
            "e": "Strongly Disagree"
        }
    ]
}
```

The answers are always the same for each question. I am trying to do a loop in javascript to  display each questiona the answers under it, something like this

```
1.I enjoy video games
RadioButton:Strongly agree   RadioButton:Agree  etc...

2. I enjoy reading
RadioButton:Strongly agree   RadioButton:Agree  etc...
```

right now i have this, but it doesn't really work

```
$.getJSON("questions.json",function(data)
{
    $.each(data, function(i,data)
    {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute("id", i);
        document.createElement("div").setAttribute("id", i);

        var div_data = "<div class='questions'><h2>" + data.Questions.Q +"</h2><br />"+

        "<input type='radio' name='q" + i + "' id='q" + i + 1+"' value='"+data.Answers.a+"'/>" +
        "<label for='q" + i + 1+"'>" + data.Answers.a + "</label>"+

        "<input type='radio' name='q" + i + "' id='q" + i + 2+"' value='"+data.Answers.b+"'/>" +
        "<label for='q" + i + 2+"'>" + data.Answers.b + "</label>" +

        "<input type='radio' name='q" + i + "' id='q" + i + 3+"' value='"+data.Answers.c+"'/>" +
        "<label for='q" + i + 3+"'>" + data.Answers.c + "</label>" +

        "<input type='radio' name='q" + i + "' id='q" + i + 4+"' value='"+data.Answers.d+"'/>" +
        "<label for='q" + i + 4+"'>" + data.Answers.d + "</label>" +

        "<input type='radio' name='q" + i + "' id='q" + i + 5+"' value='"+data.Answers.e+"'/>" +
        "<label for='q" + i + 5+"'>" + data.Answers.e + "</label>"

        +"</div>" ;

        document.getElementById("box").appendChild(div);
        div.innerHTML = div_data;

    });
});
```

Comment: This sounds like a perfect use case for [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/).

Comment: cool, i will check it out. But for now, any other suggestions?

Comment: Use Firebug of Firefox or the Chrome developer tools and put a breakpoint inside your .each block, and see what the value of i is.  You could also look at the value of data to make certain it is what you expect. I expect you need to loop over data.Questions though.

Comment: Why isn't `Questions` just a list? eg: `["I enjoy playing video games", "I enjoy reading", "I enjoy watching tv"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to loop through `data.Questions`. See the code below. I have also optimized your code, so that the HTML is appended at once, rather than separately for each element.

Another note: You should change the `i + 1, 1 + 2, 1 + 3, etc` part to something more appropriate. Currently, it's just added, because it's inside a string context. Even if you add parentheses, the logic is still flawed: For `i=1, i+2 = 3`. For `i=2, i+1` is also 3.

I have replaced `i + 1 + "'` with `i + "_1'`, to give you an idea of the right approach.

```
$.getJSON("questions.json",function(data)
{
    var html = "";
    $.each(data.Questions, function(i, question)
    {

        html += "<div id=" + i + ">" +
        "<div class='questions'><h2>" + question.Q +"</h2><br />"+

        "<input type='radio' name='q" + i + "' id='q" + i + "_1' value='"+data.Answers.a+"'/>" +
        "<label for='q" + (i + "_1'>" + data.Answers.a + "</label>"+

        "<input type='radio' name='q" + i + "' id='q" + i + "_2' value='"+data.Answers.b+"'/>" +
        "<label for='q" + i + "_2'>" + data.Answers.b + "</label>" +

        "<input type='radio' name='q" + i + "' id='q" + i + "_3' value='"+data.Answers.c+"'/>" +
        "<label for='q" + i + "_3'>" + data.Answers.c + "</label>" +

        "<input type='radio' name='q" + i + "' id='q" + i + "_4' value='"+data.Answers.d+"'/>" +
        "<label for='q" + i + "_4'>" + data.Answers.d + "</label>" +

        "<input type='radio' name='q" + i + "' id='q" + i + "_5' value='"+data.Answers.e+"'/>" +
        "<label for='q" + i + "_5'>" + data.Answers.e + "</label>"

        + "</div></div>" ;
    });
    $("#box").append(html);
});
```

Comment: I like your code much better, but i'm getting Question is not defined on line Questions.q

Comment: Try again, with a lowercase `q`. Also have a look at my comments regarding your function logic, and the edited code, which offered a better approach.

Comment: Oops nevermind, was my mistake, all looks good, but my answers i get undefined with the radio button beside

Comment: Have you copied my whole code? The error you're getting indicates that `data.Questions` is not defined. So, your JSON might not look as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't accessing the JSON properly.  `data.Questions.Q` and `data.Answers.a` is not correct.

Both `data.Questions` and `data.Answers` are arrays.  You would have to loop through those arrays and access them like `data.Questions[i].Q`.

Or change your JSON to match how you want the code to be able to iterate them.  You can fix one or the other, but the two must match.  It looks to me like you want to fix the code for the questions and fix the JSON for the answers, but that's a design decision that you can make.

Comment: I will play around with both, i understand what you mean though. I cannot access Answers from data.Questions